# Умеет ли tuple работать в цикле

Tags: c++, gcc, tuple

Необходимо пройти по всему кортежу и выводить результат каждого прохода. В итоге работы программы на экран должны быть выведены все элементы кортежа. Вот так я пытаюсь делать:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    tuple<int, char, double> some(32, 10, 33.5); //10 это перенос строки, чтобы числа не сливались.
    for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
        cout << get<i>(some);
}
return 0;
```

}
Но получаю ошибку:
`no matching function for call to 'get'`
Неужели область видимости виновата? Как еще можно реализовать цикл с элементами кортежа?
вывод который ожидаю

```
32
33.5
```

Answer (score 2):

Простой цикл не работает так как параметр для функции `std::get` должен быть константой времени компиляции. В С++17 с использованием generic lambda, fold expression и оператора запятой можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    ::std::tuple<int, char, double> some{32, 'w', 33.5};
    ::std::apply([](auto &... x){(..., static_cast<void>(::std::cout << x << ::std::endl));}, some);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но этот пример у меня не работает. А есть ли способ без привязки к стандарту c++(который будет во всех стандартах работать)?

Comment: @umd Во всех? нет. `tuple` и вариадики были добавлены только в C++11, fold expression, без которого придется прибегать к рекурсии - в С++17.

Comment: Но почему то не работает. Я правильно понимаю, что x в вашем примере нужно поменять на количество элементов кортежа?

Comment: @umd Мой пример работает как есть и ничего менять в нем не надо. "не работает" - это не описание проблемы

Comment: @umd Приводите лучше ссылки на онлайн компиляторы

Comment: [OK](https://rextester.com/YHO7805)

Comment: @umd У вас по ссылке собирается gcc 5.4 в режиме С++14.

Comment: добавил поддержку c++17и все равно та же ошибка.

Comment: @umd в gcc 5.4 нет поддержки с++17, используйте хотя бы gcc 8

Comment: установил gcc8, перенастроил qtcreator. Не работает.

Comment: @umd Опять же, "не работает" - это не описание проблемы...

Answer (score 0):

Решение без использования fold expression.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <size_t First, size_t Last>
struct tuple_index
{
};

template <size_t Last,
    typename Func,
    typename... Types>
void for_n_tuple(Func&& func, const std::tuple<Types...>& tuple, tuple_index<Last, Last>)
{
    func(std::get<Last>(tuple));
}

template <size_t First, size_t Last,
    typename Func,
    typename... Types>
void for_n_tuple(Func&& func, const std::tuple<Types...>& tuple, tuple_index<First, Last>)
{
    func(std::get<First>(tuple));
    for_n_tuple(std::forward<Func>(func), tuple, tuple_index<First + 1, Last>{});
}

template <size_t First, size_t Last,
    typename Func,
    typename... Types>
void for_tuple(Func&& func, const std::tuple<Types...>& tuple)
{
    for_n_tuple(std::forward<Func>(func), tuple, tuple_index<First, Last>{});
}

int main()
{
    auto tuple = std::make_tuple(12, "hello", 13);

    for_tuple<0, 1>([](auto&& item) {
        std::cout << item << "\n";
    }, tuple);
}
```

C++14. https://wandbox.org/permlink/8Fpx3o4PeG1NuUcX